# Flyway using Jenkins

Tags: flyway

Hello I am new to Flyway, exploring the DB migration and version tracking using Jenkins. We have Oracle DB in this project, here is the error I am getting when I try to run Baseline using Jenkins job.

```
$ /var/lib/jenkins/flyway-4.2.0/flyway -user=oracle ******** -url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.202.98.95:1521/orcl -locations=/var/lib/jenkins/flyway-4.2.0/sql info baseline
Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse

ERROR: Unable to instantiate JDBC driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver : oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
ERROR: Build step 'Invoke Flyway' failed due to errors.
```

It would be helpful if some one let me know what causing this error, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it likely you need to "install" the Oracle JDBC driver for Flyway. Find the Oracle driver (often called `ojdbc6.jar`) and copy into flyway/drivers as per the [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/).

Comment: I am planning to Install fresh oracle DB server and configure it on a VM and built Jenkins and Flyway Plugin on another VM and copy the SQL scripts/schemas from Git repo to Jenkins/Flyway VM and migrate to oracle DB and have flyway does the version tracker. Can you please confirm if this is valid scenario? Please suggest, Thanks

Comment: Your scenario is valid. This is how I've used Flyway in the past with Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your quick response :)